# Issue with JS from fields obtained through Ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) In order to create nicely displayed and managable table. To get data I use `Ajax` data source and prepared `php` script which connect to database and `echo` on screen date in `JSON` format.

`assign.php`

```
$q = "select o.id, a.id as aid, o.starttime,o.scid, count(case when v.severity = '0' then 1 else null end) as zero, 
        count(case when v.severity = '1' then 1 else null end) as one,  
        count(case when v.severity = '2' then 1 else null end) as two, 
        count(case when v.severity = '3' then 1 else null end) as three, o.starttime as start
        from topic a, project v, person o 
        where a.id = v.topic_id and a.id = o.topic_id and o.starttime = '".$_GET['date']."'
        group by o.id,o.starttime,o.scid,a.id order by id desc";
$result = $db->query($q)->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$arr = array();
foreach ($result as $row){
    if ($row['scid']==1){
        $button="<button     id=\"opener_".$row['aid']."\" class ='opener pure-button'  >Edit</button>";
    }
    else{
        $sys="";
        $button="<button id=\"opener_".$row['aid']."\" class ='opener pure-button'  >Assign</button>";
    }
    array_push($arr, array($button,$row['zero'],$row['one'],$row['two'],$row['three'],$row['starttime']));
}
$str = json_encode($arr);
$str= "{\"aaData\":".$str."}";
echo $str;
```

page displaing the table:

```
<script>

$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $( ".opener" ).click(function(event) {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
      $('<input>').attr({
        type: 'hidden',
        id: 'assetid',
        name: 'assetid',
        value: event.target.id
    }).appendTo('#systemtoasset');
    $("#divToDelete").remove(); 
    var form = document.getElementById("nazwa");
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = 'divToDelete';
    div.innerHTML = event.target.value;
    form.appendChild(div);
    });
  });</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#asset').dataTable( {
            \"bProcessing\": true,
            \"sAjaxSource\": 'ajax/testdata.php'
        } );
    } );
    </script>
<table id='asset' class='display dataTable' cellpadding='0' border='0' cellspacing='0' aria-describedby='example_info'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width='20%'>Button</th>
                    <th width='25%'>Low</th>
                    <th width='10%'>Medium</th>
                    <th width='10%'>High</th>
                    <th width='10%'>Critic</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th width='20%'>Button</th>
                    <th width='25%'>Low</th>
                    <th width='10%'>Medium</th>
                    <th width='10%'>High</th>
                    <th width='10%'>Critic</th>

                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
echo "<div id=\"dialog\"><br><br><p id='nazwa' >Select Person to link it with project</p><br><br><br>
          <form action='/?page=test' id='persontoproject' method='post' class='asholder'><input id='existing' name='existing' value='' class='txt' style='width: 125px;' /><input type='submit' name='saveperson' value='Assign'></form>
        </div>";
```

Problem is that when user click on the button displayed in table (loaded from ajax) the `JS` which handle the click is not being executed. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the click event using `$(.open)` in your posted code is for the button.

---

#### Delegate Bindings

---

You might need to delegate the event binding to the closest static element on your page instead of on the buttons directly.

If the bindings scripts are executed before the buttons are in the DOM the events will not be bound.

In that case, using jQuery 1.7 or later you can use [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with delegation, similar to this:

```
$('#asset').on('click', '.opener', function(event) {
```

I'm *assuming* that the element with the id `asset` is already on the page, otherwise use `$(document)` or `$('body')` instead.

This will bind the event to the static element (`#asset`) but delegate it to the `'.opener'` selector.

For versions of jQuery pre 1.7 [**delegate()**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to bind the event instead, similar to this:

```
$('#asset').delegate('.opener', 'click', function(event) {
```

Note the parameter order between `on()` and `delegate()` differs!

Comment: something during copy get wrong. ofc proper version of line is: `$( ".opener" ).click`. However when i try your code and use breakpoint after `click` i still get nothing. I do believe it is because content of the button is obtained through `ajax` and anytime i want to load source code of site in the browser I do not see table content.

Comment: @Grzzzzzzzzzzzzz: Assuming the generated HTML output is valid, did you try the delegate binding solution? If you are loading content through ajax any script previously to that would not find `$('.open')` as that element did not exists at the time. Use `on()` with delegation if you are using jQuery 1.7 or later or use `delegate()` if you are using jQuery 1.4.2 to jQuery 1.6.x I have updated my answer now as well to use your selector. If you still have issues could you post the HTML markup **output** as that would show the actual buttons as they are rendered.

Comment: Thank You @Francois  `$(document).on('click', '.opener', function(event) {` did the job !

Answer (score 0):

Give the submit button an id like this--

```
<input type='submit' name='saveperson' value='Assign' id="submit">
```

and then in jquery code put--

```
 $("#submit").click(function(event) {
      //// code
     });
```

Comment: Encourage people to use `on`.